# Appsync oidc with auth0 as authorisation returns unauthorised

Tags: openid-connect, auth0, aws-appsync

Along with `cognito user pools` and `api keys` I am trying to use `auth0` as an `oidc` with `aws appsync`. To be more specific, I am trying to use the multiple authorisation directives in the `appsync` schema., but keep getting the `unauhtorised` error message when using the `oidc` authorisation mode and `@aws_oidc` directive.

For my default authorisation mode, I am using the `cognito user pools`, but have also configured the use of `API keys`.

I now want to use the `@aws_oidc` directive in my schema so that users coming from `auth0` can perform actions against my API. I have configured in the `appsync` settings a OIDC authorization mode and have set as the issuer URL the same value as the `iss` value from the `auth0` `jwt` token used to authorise against auth0.

I have checked that the token is a `RS256 token` and that is it also a valid token, and if I use it to send a curl request to the `/userinfo` on `auth0` I can retrieve the users' attributes.

I have the following mutation in my schema, that I use to create items.

```js
type Mutation @aws_oicd @aws_iam
@aws_cognito_user_pools {
    createItem(input: CreateItemInput!): Item
    auth0CreateItem(bearerToken: String!, input: CreateItemInput!): Item @aws_oicd
```

This mutation works if set and use the `@aws_apikey` directive as well as with the `@aws_cognito_user_pools` directive and I can create an item just fine.

However when I add the `@aws_oidc` directive, it returns unauthorised for valid token.

Why is it returning this message? What is aws doing in the background that the token is not working? Are there properties missing in my token?

This is my token.

[image]

The iss value in the token matches the issuer url in the appsync settings when creating the authorisation mode.

[image]

And this is the response from using the `appsync` console to perform a query.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So a simple fix really.

It turns out that the AuthTTL and Issued At TTL values also need to be present in the token for the configuration to be correct, and the values need to match.

In my case all I needed to do was delete those values in the appsync oidc settings.

This can be found in the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security.html#openid-connect-authorization)